# How to solve the follow tensor completion problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, tensors

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(\mathcal{X})= \| \mathcal{X} - \mathcal{A} \|_F^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathcal{X}_\Omega = \mathcal{T}_\Omega
\end{array}$$

where $\mathcal{X}$, $\mathcal{A}$  and $\mathcal{T}$ are all third-order tensor, and $\Omega$ is the observed element.  $\mathcal{X}_\Omega = \mathcal{T}_\Omega$ means that their observed elements should be the same.

An solution for above is from the paper (its equation (24) ):https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6979248

I place its solution here:

By introducing Lagrangian multiplier  $\mathcal{Q}$ for the constraint $\mathcal{X}_\Omega = \mathcal{T}_\Omega$

we have the Lagrangian function:

$F(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Q}) = \|\mathcal{X} - \mathcal{A} \|_F^2 + <\mathcal{Q}, \mathcal{X}_\Omega - \mathcal{T}_\Omega>$

take derivative to zero, we have the KKT conditions

$2(\mathcal{X} - \mathcal{A}) + \mathcal{Q}_\Omega =0$

$ \mathcal{X}_\Omega - \mathcal{T}_\Omega = 0$

they then get the solution

$\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{T}_\Omega +\mathcal{A}_{\Omega^C}$

where ${\Omega^C}$ is the complement of ${\Omega}$

My question is that:
How to get the solution from above KKT condition? it seems that the $\mathcal{Q}_\Omega$ is gone.

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $\mathcal{Q}_{\Omega}$ is zero on $\Omega^C$. Thus, from the first KKT equation you have that on $\Omega^C$, $\mathcal X = \mathcal A $. On the other hand, on $\Omega$, $\mathcal X = \mathcal T$. Hence, the final equation follows: $\mathcal X = \mathcal T_\Omega + \mathcal A_{\Omega^C}$.